# Identify runs on array with ruby

Tags: ruby, pattern-matching

If we have an array

```
array = [1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3 ]
```

How can we identify the run (amount of consecutive numbers with same value) of a given number?
By example:

```
run_pattern_for(array, 0) -> 2
run_pattern_for(array, 3) -> 1
run_pattern_for(array, 1) -> 1
run_pattern_for(array, 2) -> 0
```

There are no runs for 2 because there are no consecutive apparitions of two. 
There are one run for 3 because there are only one apparition with the tree as consecutive numbers.

Comment: how are you getting this pattern out of the array??

Comment: Define "the run of a given number".

Comment: I think he means consecutive numbers of the same value.

Comment: Run as @LuisOrtegaAraneda says

Comment: @LuisOrtegaAraneda What makes it in case of `0` the value `2` instead of `3`? Can you tell for sure? Don't try to guess. It is the OP's responsibility to make it clear. On top of that, that is clearly not the case.

Comment: Because you have two times a list of consecutive 0's.

Comment: @LuisOrtegaAraneda ... and ...?

Comment: @LuisOrtegaAraneda By your phrase "consecutive numbers", did you mean "the numbers of (chunks of) consecutive numbers"? If that is the case, then you should study English. What your wrote does not mean what you thought you meant.

Comment: @sawa, i just edited the question. Can you get it now ?

Comment: @ArnaldoIgnacioGasparVéjar According to your definition, a single isolated instance of a number does not count as a (trivial) consecutive number?

Comment: @sawa I meant exactly what's in the comment.

Comment: A single isolated instance wouldn't count as the example is not counting them.

Comment: @sawa, yes. A single number doesn't count.

Comment: @sawa I'm not the OP in case you didn't notice it... I'm just trying to help. Regards.

Comment: May I suggest an edit to clarify?  "A "run" is a maximum-length sequence of identical elements from `array` that contains at least two elements.  For example, `[0,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2]` contains two runs of  1', one run of `2` and zero runs of `0` and `3`. I would like to construct a hash whose keys are the elements of `array.uniq` and whose values are the numbers of runs for each of those keys."  I see there are two votes to close, no doubt because the question is clear.  It would be a shame for it to close, as it's an interesting question.

Comment: There are now four votes to close your question. If you do not edit to clarify, it likely will be closed.  Why would you refuse to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try:

```
class Array
  def count_runs(element)
    chunk {|n| n}.count {|a,b| a == element && b.length > 1}
  end
end

a = [1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3 ]
a.count_runs 0   #=> 2
a.count_runs 3   #=> 1
a.count_runs 1   #=> 1
a.count_runs 2   #=> 0
```

Comment: Wow, very great answer, i never knew chunk function until now

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @BroiSatse that [Enumerable#chunk](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) should be used here, but I would like to show how an enumerator could be employed directly to solve this problem, using the methods [Enumerator#next](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) and [Enumerator#peek](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek).

**Code**

```
def count_em(array)
  return [] if array.empty?
  h = Hash.new(0)
  enum = array.each
  loop do
    x = enum.next
    if x == enum.peek
      h[x] += 1
      enum.next until (enum.peek != x)
    else
      h[x] = 0 unless h.key?(x)
    end
  end
  h
end
```

**Example**

```
array = [1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3 ]
count_em(array) #=> {1=>1, 0=>2, 2=>0, 3=>1}
```

**Explanation**

Suppose

```
array = [1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2]
h = Hash.new(0)
enum = array.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2]:each>

x = enum.next #=> 1
enum.peek     #=> 1
```

so `x == enum.peek #=> true`, meaning there is a run of at least two 1's, so wish execute:

```
h[x] += 1 #=> h[1] += 1
```

which means

```
h[1] = h[1] + 1
```

Since `h` does not have a key `1`, `h[x]` on the right side of the equality set to zero, the default value we established when creating the hash.  Therefore, the hash `h` is now `{ 1=>1 }`.  Now we want need to enumerate and discard any more 1's in the run:

```
enum.next until (enum.peek != x)

enum.next #=> 1
enum.peek #=> 1
enum.next #=> 1
enum.peek #=> 0
```

Now go back to the top of the loop:

```
x = enum.next #=> 0
enum.peek     #=> 2
```

Since `(x == enum.peek) => (0 == 2) => false`, and `h.key?(x) => false`, we set

```
h[0] = 0
```

and the hash is now  `{ 1=>1, 0=>0 }`.  Returning again to the top of the loop,

```
x = enum.next #=> 2
enum.peek     #=> 2
```

Since `(x == enum.peek) => (2 == 2) => true`, we execute:

```
h[2] += 1 #=> 1
```

so now `h => {1=>1, 0=>0, 2=>1}`.  Now when we execute

```
x = enum.next #=> 2
enum.peek #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

The exception is rescued by [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop).  That is, raising a `StopIteration` error is one way to break out of the loop, causing the last line of the method to be executed and returned:

```
h #=> {1=>1, 0=>0, 2=>1}
```

(Note this result differs from that in the example above because it is for a different `array`.)

Answer (score 2):

Ruby 2.2, which was released roughly seven months after this question was posted, gave us a method that has application here, [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when):

```
array.slice_when { |i,j| i != j }.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |a,h|
  h[a.first] += (a.size > 1) ? 1 : 0 }  
  #=> {1=>1, 0=>2, 2=>0, 3=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple task; Here are two different ways I've done it:

```
array = [1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3 ]

hash = Hash[array.group_by { |e| e }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.size] }] 
# => {1=>2, 0=>5, 2=>1, 3=>4}
```

And:

```
hash = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = 0 }
array.each { |e| hash[e] += 1 }
hash # => {1=>2, 0=>5, 2=>1, 3=>4}
```

Once you have the hash the rest is easy:

```
hash[0] # => 5
hash[1] # => 2
hash[2] # => 1
hash[3] # => 4
```

If it's possible you'll request a count for a number that didn't exist in the array, and want a numeric response instead of `nil`, use something like:

```
Integer(hash[4]) # => 0
```

`Integer(...)` converts nil to `0` for you.

In the first example above, [`group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) will do the heavy lifting, and results in:

```
array.group_by { |e| e } # => {1=>[1, 1], 0=>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 2=>[2], 3=>[3, 3, 3, 3]}
```

The `map` statement simply converts the array to its size.

Comment: This is not what OP wants to achieve.